# How to add background color to code to code box

Tags: highlighting, pandoc

How do I add a background color to the following?

```
\begin{lstlisting}

{
  "client_id": "string",
  "api_key": "string",
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\lstset{...}` to change settings on your listing; in this case, you want to change the `backgroundcolor` setting. The `xcolor` package provides colors you can use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}

{
      "client_id": "string",
        "api_key": "string",
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{document}
```

Additionally, you can define your own colors using the `\definecolor` macro. For example, to use hex color codes, you could use `\definecolors{lightblue}{HTML}{0088FF}`, and then reference the color `lightblue` in your background color setting.

For more information on colors, the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) has a more in-depth description.